# Making multiple balls move in pygame

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I need to make the balls in this code move around randomly. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I am new to programming and this may be badly coded so any help would be appreciated. Right now the code makes a character in the middle of the screen that you can move up or down and it makes one ball in the top left corner of the screen that does not move. I want multiple balls on the screen and eventually I want the balls to be moving around randomly and if they collide with the character you lose this simple game.

```
from pygame import *
import random

class Ball(sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, numballs, balls = []):
        sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = image.load('ball.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.numballs = numballs
        self.balls = balls


    def multipleBalls(self):
        for count in range(self.numballs):
            self.balls.append(dict)
            self.balls[count] = {'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'xmove': random.randint(1,2), 'ymove':random.randint(1,2)}

    def ballMove(self):
        for count in range(self.numballs):
            self.balls[count]['x'] = self.balls[count]['x'] + self.balls[count]['xmove']
            self.balls[count]['y'] = self.balls[count]['y'] + self.balls[count]['ymove']

    def ballsOnScreen(self):
        for count in range(self.numballs):
            self.screen.blit(self.image, (self.balls[count]['x'], self.balls[count]['y']))


    def ballBarrier(self):
        for count in range(self.numballs):
            if self.balls[count]['x'] > 620:
                self.balls[count]['xmove'] = random.randint(-2, 0)
            if self.balls[count]['x'] < -10:
                self.balls[count]['xmove'] = random.randint(0, 2)
            if self.balls[count]['y'] > 470:
                self.balls[count]['ymove'] = random.randint(-2, 0)
            if self.balls[count]['y'] < -10:
                self.balls[count]['ymove'] = random.randint(0, 2)

    def manageBall(self):
        self.multipleBalls()
        self.ballsOnScreen()
        self.ballMove()
        self.ballBarrier()

class Character(sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, xy):
        sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = image.load('character.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx, self.rect.centery = xy
        self.movementspeed = 1
        self.velocity = 0


    def down(self):
        self.velocity += self.movementspeed

    def up(self):
        self.velocity -= self.movementspeed

    def characterMove(self, dy):
        if self.rect.bottom + dy > 480:
            self.rect.bottom = 480
        elif self.rect.top + dy < 0:
            self.rect.top = 0
        else:
            self.rect.y += dy

    def update(self):
        self.characterMove(self.velocity)


class Game(object):
    def __init__(self):
        init()
        key.set_repeat(1, 30)
        self.screen = display.set_mode((640, 480))
        self.clock = time.Clock()
        display.set_caption('Game')
        event.set_allowed([QUIT, KEYDOWN, KEYUP])
        self.background = Surface((640, 480))
        self.background.fill((0,0,0))
        self.screen.blit(self.background, (0,0))
        display.flip()
        self.sprites = sprite.RenderUpdates()
        self.character = Character((320, 240))
        self.sprites.add(self.character)
        self.ball = Ball(5)
        self.sprites.add(self.ball)

    def run(self):
        running = True
        while running == True:
            self.clock.tick(60)
            running = self.handleEvents()
            display.set_caption('game %d fps' % self.clock.get_fps())
            for sprite in self.sprites:
                sprite.update()
            self.sprites.clear(self.screen, self.background)
            dirty = self.sprites.draw(self.screen)
            display.update(dirty)
            self.ball.manageBall()

    def handleEvents(self):
        for e in event.get():
            if e.type == QUIT:
                return False

            elif e.type == KEYDOWN:
                if e.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    return False
                if e.key == K_UP:
                    self.character.up()
                if e.key == K_DOWN:
                    self.character.down()

        return True



def main():
    game = Game()
    game.run()
main()
```

Comment: You should explain what your code actually does, and how that compares to what you'd like it to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used the Sprite class before so this was a good exercise. :)

I fixed your code, just change the image paths back to your icon locations and you should be good to go. The print statements might need reformatting if you're running an older version of Python.

I take out the forced call to the Sprite **init** method in the Ball and Character classes, it won't let me add them to the game.sprites render group. Not sure why.

I'm running Python 3.2.2 and Pygame 1.9.2pre so YMMV. :)

Controls:

UP / DOWN = Move your dude.

R = add a new, random ball.

```
from pygame import *
import random

SCREEN_WIDTH = 640
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480

FPS = 60

class Ball(sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, xy = (0,0), xm = 0, ym = 0):
        sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.img_load('evil_balloon_32x32.png')
        self.rect.centerx, self.rect.centery = xy

        self.xmove = xm
        self.ymove = ym

    def update(self):
        self.move()
        self.ballBarrier()

    def move(self):
        self.rect.x += self.xmove
        self.rect.y += self.ymove

    def img_load(self, filename):
        self.image = image.load(filename)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def ballBarrier(self):
        """
        Checks to make sure ball is within bounds, adjusts movement speed if it's not
        """
        if self.rect.right > SCREEN_WIDTH:
            self.xmove = random.randint(-2, 0)
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.xmove = random.randint(0, 2)
        if self.rect.bottom > SCREEN_HEIGHT:
            self.ymove = random.randint(-2, 0)
        if self.rect.top < 0:
            self.ymove = random.randint(0, 2)

class ball_manager():
    def __init__(self, numballs = 5, balls = []):      
        self.blist = balls

        if numballs > 0:
            self.multipleBalls(numballs) # moved this here so balls get init'd only once

    def update(self):
        """
        Update position of all balls
        """
        for ball in self.blist:
            self.ballMove(ball)

    def add_ball(self, xy = (0,0), xm = 0, ym = 0):
        self.blist.append(Ball(xy, xm, ym)) # appends a random ball

    def multipleBalls(self, numballs):
        for i in range(numballs):
            self.add_ball((random.randint(0, SCREEN_WIDTH),
                          random.randint(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT)),
                          random.randint(-2,2),
                          random.randint(-2,2))

class Character(sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, xy):
        sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.img_load()

        self.rect.centerx, self.rect.centery = xy

        self.movementspeed = 1
        self.velocity = 0

    def down(self):
        self.velocity += self.movementspeed

    def up(self):
        self.velocity -= self.movementspeed

    def characterMove(self, dy):
        if self.rect.bottom + dy > SCREEN_HEIGHT:
            self.rect.bottom = SCREEN_HEIGHT
            self.velocity = 0
        elif self.rect.top + dy < 0:
            self.rect.top = 0
            self.velocity = 0
        else:
            self.rect.y += dy

    def update(self):
        self.characterMove(self.velocity)

    def img_load(self):
        self.image = image.load("scary_clown_32x32.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

class Game(object):
    def __init__(self):
        init()
        key.set_repeat(1, 30)
        self.screen = display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
        self.clock = time.Clock()
        display.set_caption('Game')

        event.set_allowed([QUIT, KEYDOWN, KEYUP])
        self.background = Surface((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
        self.background.fill((0,0,0))
        self.screen.blit(self.background, (0,0))
        display.flip()

        self.sprites = sprite.RenderUpdates()

        self.character = Character((SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2))

        self.sprites.add(self.character)

        self.balls = ball_manager(5)

        for ball in self.balls.blist:
            self.sprites.add(ball)

    def run(self):
        running = True
        while running == True:
            self.clock.tick(FPS)
            running = self.handleEvents()
            display.set_caption('game %d fps' % self.clock.get_fps())

            self.sprites.clear(self.screen, self.background)

            for sprite in self.sprites:
                sprite.update()

            dirty = self.sprites.draw(self.screen)
            display.update(dirty)


    def handleEvents(self):
        for e in event.get():
            if e.type == QUIT:
                return False

            elif e.type == KEYDOWN:
                if e.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    return False
                if e.key == K_UP:
                    self.character.up()
                if e.key == K_DOWN:
                    self.character.down()
                if e.key == K_r:
                   self.sprites.add(Ball((random.randint(0, SCREEN_WIDTH),
                          random.randint(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT)),
                          random.randint(-2,2),
                          random.randint(-2,2))) 


        return True

def main():
    game = Game()
    game.run()
    quit()

main()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: Thanks a million. This worked perfectly and it helped me to understand coding a little better.

Comment: Good times! Glad I could help, the Sprite class is pretty cool.